# RandomChoice inside RandomChoice

Tags: random

I have spent a half hour searching Mathematica.SE for information on this topic, with no luck. The code is:

```
RandomChoice[
  {40, 30, 1} -> 
    {BlockRandom[RandomChoice[{0, 0}], RandomSeeding -> Automatic],
     BlockRandom[RandomChoice[{1, 5}], RandomSeeding -> Automatic], 
     BlockRandom[RandomChoice[{6, 10}], RandomSeeding -> Automatic]}, 
   20]
```

A typical output is:

> ```
> {0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0}
> ```

Why does the code give only the same two numbers repeatedly? isn't `RandomSeeding` supposed to prevent this type of output?

Comment: Use RuleDelayed instead of Rule, e.g., `RandomChoice[{40, 30, 1} :> {..}]`.

Comment: That works great, thanks!

Comment: It looks like using RuleDelayed also obviates using BlockRandom and RandomSeeding!